# Rails 5.1.: get records from association for each datetime interval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have Model named `Task` with method `dates` which gives me this output (it can be different and multiple DateTime intervals):

```
[{:from=>2017-09-04 00:00:00 +0300, :to=>2017-09-04 05:59:59 +0300},
 {:from=>2017-09-05 12:00:00 +0300, :to=>2017-09-05 19:59:59 +0300}
```

then in same Model there is another method `inventory`, where for each `task` I want to get corresponding `Inventory` model records.

At the moment I'm trying to do something like this:

```
self.inventories.where(date: self.from..self.to)
```

This does not work, because `from` and `to` comes from data structure above and there are no such columns in my DB. I've set appropriate association in my model and I can do `self.inventories`.

Is there a way to do Rails query in order to grab matching records for each of my `dates` intervals, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your asking how to access data inside an array, you can loop through each data.

```
def self.dates
  #generate intervals as array of hashes
end

def self.inventories
  [].tap do |inventories|
    dates.each do |date|
      from = date[:from]
      to = date[:to]
      inventories << self.inventories.where(date: from..to)
    end
  end
end
```

and ensure to use #flatten since it would be nested in arrays

inventories.flatten

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working. I believe you mean `inventories.flatten` has to be used for result data, right?

Comment: yup you need to use #flatten to remove nested arrays